# INDEX/MATCH lookup_value referencing a cell that contains an index/match formula is giving a N/A error

Tags: excel, xlsx

When doing an INDEX/MATCH formula in cell `H14` the lookup_value part of my formula references a cell(`N5`) that contains an IF/INDEX/MATCH formula. I know my formula is correct but it returns `"N/A"`. It has something to do with the cell value it's looking up but I don't know what.

H14 formula is

```
=INDEX(OSARP!L6:L466,MATCH(Summary!N5,OSARP!H6:H466,0))
```

and it returns and `N/A` error.

N5 formula is

```
=IF($H$5="","",INDEX(Table_owssvr_1[GUUID],MATCH($H$5,Table_owssvr_1[Emp Name],0)))
```

I need it to use the result of `N5` formula which is an ID number that was index/matched from another sheet.

Worksheet

[image: Worksheet]

Comment: Is your `$H$5` lookup working?

Comment: Did you try to trace the precedents? This might indicate what's going wrong.

Comment: Also you could click on that exclamation mark next o `N5` and go to `Show calculation steps...`

Comment: What does N5 show? A valid ID?

Comment: Maybe also use Trim to be sure of no excess white space.

Comment: Yes my H5 lookup is working @zipa

Comment: There's no excess characters or spaces to trim @qharr

Comment: When I show calculation steps it shows the issue comes in when referencing N5, it put the number in quotation marks

Comment: Try : `=INDEX(OSARP!L6:L466,MATCH(Summary!N5*1,OSARP!H6:H466,0)) `

Comment: Yes that works @J.Doe. Thank you!